# Contour Labels disappearing when Saving

Tags: qgis, shapefile

The labels I made on my Contours through the label tab in the properties panel disappear after I save my QGIS project as a shapefile.

Comment: Can you provide more details or/and a screenshot of your properties panel? And you can't save a project as a shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS you save .qgs files as project files and shapefiles are .shp files. Information like labelling or symbology can be saved as a .qml file. this link provides further information nathanw.net/2014/03/22/all-the-q-files

Here is a screenshot where to save symbology / label as .qml[image]

Comment: Where do I go through to save the labels as a QML.  I tried through Right-Click save-as and that is not an option and also through the label tab in properties it doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: i edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  The .qml isn't able to be brought into autocad however.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible through the .dxf file. Here again is a link to a similiar problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24806/37235

Comment: The .dxf file that I save does not contain the contour symbols. Is there a button I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

shapefiles can only save either point or lines or polygones geometries (No text, no styling) so save as qqis-project

Comment: How is it possible to save the text of the contour labels then as well to be able to bring into Autocad?

Comment: So you want edit your shapefiles in qgis with labels and then export it to autocad?

Comment: @DirkBrunken exactly.  I already have the labels on the contours as I want them in QGIS.  I just need to figure out how to keep the formatting and labels on the contours when I export it.

Comment: Maybe this link to another similiar question is useful? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192446/37235

Comment: @DirkBrunken I saved as a DXF and then brought it into cad but it is empty.  Nothing comes in.  I will keep trying.